# Clarification on schwartz chapter 9

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, field-theory

In the first printing, eq. 9.27 reads $$ k^\mu (p_1^\mu + p_3^\mu ) =(p_1^\mu - p_3^\mu)(p_1^\mu + p_3^\mu) = p_3^2 - p_1^2 = m^2 - m^2 = 0\tag{9.27}$$ for a $t$-channel diagram for $ e^- e^- \rightarrow e^- e^- $ and p3 and p1 form the two upper legs.

This implies that $ \bar p_3^2 + \bar p_1^2 = 0 $  which implies that $ \bar p_1^2 = - \bar p_3^2 $. If you know the latter fact, this makes the former identity obvious.

This seems to make sense because this would mean that $  p_1^2 + p_3^2 + k^2 = 0 + \bar p_1^2 $ if $ k^2 = \bar p_1^2 $ (using the same rest frame) which it should be for an on shell photon (EDIT: this is probably wrong)

So, does $ \bar p_3^2 = - \bar p_1^2 $ deduced from the fact that we assume the photon is on shell, or can you deduce this without knowing that? I would assume the former, but I'd like to make sure.

(my confusion also partially comes from the fact that Schwartz goes $ p_3^2 - p_1^2 = m^2 - m^2 $ so we're already assuming that they ought to have the same invariant mass... so I'm wondering if this is obvious.)

edit: alternatively he really did mean both vectors should be upper indexed so that it's $ \bar p_3^2 - \bar p_1^2 = 0  $... but then what would k be?? $ \bar p_1^2 $ still? and in this case, how are you sure that $ \bar p_3^2 = \bar p_1^2 $ beforehand?

Comment: In that section, he is doing $e^+e^-$ scattering so obviously all the masses are the same.

Comment: @Prahar he was doing $ e^- e^- $ in my edition-- do you mean specifically the invariant mass?

Comment: ya, its $e^-e^-$ scattering. I read it wrong. What do you mean here by invariant mass? I simply mean mass of electron. Since all external particles there are electrons, we have $p_i^2 = m^2$ where $m$ is the mass of the electron.

Comment: PS - I know what the term "invariant mass" means, but it does not apply in the current context. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Prahar then doesn't my answer still hold, since we'd like that $ e^-  \rightarrow e^- \gamma $ holds so that the invariant mass before and after is the same? from the below, it would work only if $ \gamma^2 = 0 $. why should the photon be virtual?

Comment: @Prahar also, thanks for your responses so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140256/discussion-between-prahar-and-anon-jpg).

Answer (score -2):

ok, this is a relatively silly misconception; im a little tired.

anyway,
k is a photon, then $ k^\mu k_\mu =  k^2 = 0 $. This means that $ p_3^2 - p_1^2 = 0 $ for conservation of the invariant mass which is what we want.

i do think that he meant to write $ k_\mu (p^\mu... ) $ and so on but assumed we'd figure it out.

EDIT: this is wrong for the reasons Prahar explains. the true answer literally is just that both the incoming and outgoing particles at the vertex are the same and consequently have the same mass, so $ p_3^2 - p_1^2 = m^2 -m^2 = 0$.

The reason I was confused was that I assumed there was some kind of invariant rest mass conservation at each vertex (there isn't) and was getting mixed up on whether or not the photon was on shell or virtual.

I'd prefer to keep this answer up in case someone else has the same misconception.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The photon is a virtual one so it is not on-shell. Rather, momentum conservation at a vertex implies that $k^\mu = p_1^\mu - p_3^\mu$ so $k_\mu ( p_1^\mu + p_3^\mu ) = ( p_{1\mu} - p_{3\mu}) ( p_1^\mu + p_3^\mu ) = p_1^2 - p_3^2 = m^2 - m^2 = 0$.